# Calling WinRS when using a password with spaces

Tags: powershell-remoting, winrm, winrs

I'm trying to call WinRS for some of our automated scripts. I've run into an issue when attempting to pass a password with spaces for the -p argument.

For example,

```
winrs http://server:5985 -p:my password -u:user dir
```

fails with the message

```
winrs.exe:The parameter is incorrect.
```

Quoting the argument doesn't seem to help,

```
winrs http://server:5985 -p:"my password" -u:user dir
```

it fails with the message

```
Winrs error:Access is denied.
```

If I type in my password, everything works as expected, however this is not an option for the workflow we're building.

Is it possible to pass a password containing spaces to WinRS? If not, is there a workaround that does not include manual typing?

Answer (score 1):

The host needs to be prefixed by "-r:"
like so:

winrs -r:http://server:5985 -p:my password -u:user "dir"

Answer (score 0):

Try using a backtick before the space.  The backtick is powershell's escape character:

```
winrs http://server:5985 -p:my` password -u:user dir
```

This should prevent the space from being interpreted as a delimiter.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. Now I'm getting:

    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I assume because it's trying to interpret it as a command.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the caret escape character. I believe one of the following combinations might work:

```
winrs http://server:5985 ^"-p:my` password^" -u:user dir
```

or

```
winrs http://server:5985 -p:^"my` password^" -u:user dir
```

Courtesy of
https://www.drupal.org/node/1242152